# Building static sites in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, static

I have recently finished the book: Node Beginner Book and I want to build static websites and real time web apps. I have a project idea that is basically just an eCommerce website. From what iv'e heard, node.js is very good at real time data transfer between the client and the server but is it possible to make general websites instead of real time single page apps in node.js?

If so, could you please point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: yes, with the right programming skills you can make any kind of website in nodejs. Expressjs would be good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [ExpressJS framework](http://expressjs.com/) and [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) you can serve a directory hierarchy of static files with a single line of code.

For example:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Tell express to look in the 'public' sub-directory for any requested file and serve it statically from there if a match is found.

Other route handlers you configure with Express also have a crack at serving the file so you can freely mix static files and dynamic files.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are understanding. I don't want to just display html pages or there would be no point at all. For example could I do something like this: Just say I had categories in my database for e.g: Hats, Scarves, T-Shirts so this would be looped on my home page. Just say that I then clicked on "Hats", then it would come up with all associated hats that are in my database. Could I possibly do something like this in node.js?

Comment: @mre12345 - Please rewrite your question.  What you just put in that comment is not what I got out of your question at all.  Your title implies you're asking how to build static websites which is exactly what I answered.  I still don't 'really understand what you are asking.  A node.js server can build any kind of website you want.  As much static or dynamic as you want or any possible mix.  A list of hats from a database would probably be best done using a template system (I use handlebars, but there are dozens of different choices) combined with custom Express handlers for each dynamic page.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good frameworks available in node.js for serving static resources.

I've personally used [Harp.js](http://harpjs.com) in several projects with success. It not only lets you easily serve static content, but aldo supports several template for languages for abstraction and dynamic behavior. It can also works nicely with other frameworks like express.

## Revised

Meteor.js, sails.js or similar framework seems to be what you're looking for.